# Transformed (shrunk) iframe still takes up space even within a div

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have been trying to experiment with using iframes to give live thumbnails of other sites on my website. I have managed to code the iframes so that they are scaled down, but they still "occupy" the space for their original size. The main problem is that because of where I have my iframes positioned (float: right), they are forcing my website to extend beyond the edge of the screen on smaller devices. The bottom iframes are also pushing the screen edge below my sticky footer, resulting in the footer no longer sticking to the bottom.

I have tried enclosing the iframes in divs to restrict the size, but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class='frameLimit'>
    <iframe src='http://www.theinkslinger.co.uk' class='thumbs' scrolling='no'>
        <p class='smaller'>Your browser does not support iframes</p>
    </iframe>
</div>

<h3 class='port'>The Ink Slinger</h3>
<p class='smaller'>My personal website and blog</p>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
iframe.thumbs {
overflow: hidden;
width: 960px;
height: 480px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

border: #49483e solid 0.25em;
border-radius: 1em;

-moz-transform: scale(.3);
-webkit-transform: scale(.3);
-o-transform: scale(.3);
transform: scale(.3);

-moz-transform-origin:0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
-o-transform-origin:0 0;
transform-origin:0 0;

}


p.smaller {
font-size: large !important;
}

h3.port {
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;

text-align: left;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: sans-serif;

text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000000;
}

.frameLimit {
width: 320px !important;
height: 160px !important;

padding: 0;
margin: 0;

float: right;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

I would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved your issue with `overflow:hidden` on the container itself. Also I scaled down it's width and height accordingly.

Also added

```
.bottom { clear: both; }
```

class to your bottom division.

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TkPEy/1/).

Let me know if it helps.

EDIT: Updated fiddle

Comment: That is outstanding. Thank you so much, that has been driving me nuts!

Comment: You're wellcome. Just one small thing - make sure you set your     .frameLimit width/height in em's while taking the border size into account. I used pixels and it's not the perfect size that way.